# Asset pipeline in a Rails 3.2.11 app works fine with Ruby 1.9.3 but stops working in Ruby 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My asset pipeline was working fine in Ruby 1.9.3. When I upgrade to 2.0.0 It stops working.

In Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

In application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-affix
//= require bootstrap-alert
...
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require sitengine.js
//= require_tree .
```

Result from .../assets/application.js in browser:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-affix
//= require bootstrap-alert
...
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require my_app.js
//= require_tree .
;
```

Two questions:

1. Have you experienced this? If you have, would love to have a comment from you.
2. Have you found a solution? (Thanks in advance for your answer.)

Thanks!

Comment: Mine is working fine. Have you tried updating all your gems with ``bundle update`` ?

Comment: @Intrepidd, that did it. Surprised... thought I had done that. If you make your comment an answer, I'll select it. Thanks!

Comment: I just did it, thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I updated all my gems with `bundle update` and that did the trick.

No idea why, probably some gems were updated for ruby 2.